# How to generate a random number with fixed length only with 0's and 1's and a fixed amount of 1's?

Tags: php, loops, random, while-loop, numbers

I did some research, but didn't found any solution for my question.

What I want to archive:

Generate a random number out of 0's (`$min`) and 1's (`$max`), but with a fixed amount (`$many`) of 1's in the random number. The random number should have a length of 6 as in my while loop (`while($xLoop <= 6)`).

Here is my current code:

```
$min = 0;
$max = 1;

$many = 3;
$xLoop = 1;

while($xLoop <= 6) {
    $nRand = mt_rand($min,$max);

    if($nRand == 1){ //if random number comes out number 1
         $many--; // Prevent number 1 more then $many...

         //Do something...
    }else{ //if random number comes out not number 1
         //Do something and still looping until get 6 times
    }

    echo $nRand.' - '.$many.'</br>'; //For debugin... i want to see how many number 1 comes out.

    $xLoop++;
}
```

It will loop 6 times, so we have a random number of the length 6, but I want a fixed amount of 1's in my random number, which is `$many` (here 3). And the rest filled with 0's until we reach the length 6.

How can I fix this code? Or is there  a simpler way?

Comment: I guess you have to make your question clear enough so that everyone can understand and help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

No need for a loop. Just first fill an array with 1's `$many` times. Then [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) the array with the 0's which you fill up until `$length` elements.

At the end just [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the array and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it to print it

```
<?php

    $min = 0;
    $max = 1;

    $many = 3;
    $length = 6;

    $arr = array_fill(0, $many, $min);
    $arr = array_merge($arr, array_fill($many, $length-$many, $max));
    shuffle($arr);

    echo implode("", $arr);

?>
```

possible output:

```
011010
```

Comment: please explain the downVote, so I can improve this answer.

Comment: @FrancisAlvin I don't have a question. This should be an answer to the question from OP

Comment: aha.. yeah right. You have an interesting solution there. :) @Rizier123  and sorry I was addressing it to Welly.

Comment: sorry.. what more question please.. how can i separate between 011010 so i can put it in table like column 1 is 0, column 2 is 1 etc

Comment: @WellyTunggala If you do: `print_r($arr);` you will see you have each digit as an element in the array and can access/use it.

Comment: @WellyTunggala np. (BTW: Just edited my answer. I had 1 and 0 hardcoded, just changed it out with `$min` and `$max`)